# Why ionic ion-input type="number" does not allow comma in iOS even if number format is "1.234.567,89"?

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, ionic-framework, angular-reactive-forms

My ionic app has a reactive form with an `<ion-input type="numeric" inputmode="decimal" ...>`.
When i build the app in ios (Iphone 14, ios 16) the keyboard shows a comma `,` but when i input a value with comma, the `form.value` becomes null.

It only happens with number format setted to "1.234.567,89", with "1,234,567.89" it works but i need both.

Versions:
Ionic 6
Angular 14

Comment: That looks like a locale issue. The first number is valid in locales where . Is the place separator and , is the decimal separator, but if that isn't the current device locale I am not surprised that it is rejected.

Comment: Sure. The keyboard is showing correctly the `,` when `,` is the separator and the `.` when the `.` is the separator for the locale, but when the separator is `,` a number like 45,6 should be valid and it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ion-input uses the browser's `<input>` tag to display (as seen here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input) because of that it has the same behavior.

Inputs of type number will use the number system of the browser locale (ex: will allow commas in countries that use commas and decimals in countries that use decimals).

If you need both you should use a text input and the ion-input pattern property with a regular expression to validate the field as shown here https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#pattern. The below code will allow decimal and comma delineated numbers

```
<ion-input type="text" pattern="(\d+(?:[\.\,]\d+)+)"/>
```

Comment: I tried it..
It works but i need one more thing. 
What if the number ends with `,` or `.`? like 45, or 59.
I need this case as a valid input.

Comment: You can modify the regex to fit that pattern. (\d+(?:[\.\,]\d*)+) should allow numbers without anything after the decimal/comma.